# Floating Action Button position

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

I have a Fragment in the bottom of my layout, and when it is shown it overlaps with my FAB.
So, how can I make FAB to depend on this Fragment (lift FAB when the Fragment is shown, just like it does when Snackbar is shown)?

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour between the `FAB` and the `Snackbar` is result of having the `CoordinatorLayout` as the direct parent of the two views. The coordinator layout handles this animation effect.

> Coordinator layout is used as a container for a specific
>   interaction with one or more child views.
>
> By specifying Behaviors for child views of a CoordinatorLayout you can
>   provide many different interactions within a single parent and those
>   views can also interact with one another.

Reference: [Coordinator Layout | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html)

So your view holding the fragment needs to have a `Behaviour` implementation for it. This will define how your views interact with other views.

Check this [guide](https://medium.com/google-developers/intercepting-everything-with-coordinatorlayout-behaviors-8c6adc140c26#.tlavhsgtg) for how to create `Behaviours` for `CoordinatorLayout`.

For `FloatingActionButton` this behaviour is already defined in its class. Check source [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.java?autodive=0%2F%2F#489).

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/mediaPlayerControlBar">

        <RelativeLayout>



        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            app:layout_behavior="com.unimusic.ScrollAwareFABBehavior"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:elevation="4dp"/>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <fragment android:name="com.unimusic.mediaPlayerControlBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/mediaPlayerControlBar"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/snackbarPosition"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Basicly, I've made Relative layout a root component instead of CoordinatorLayout.